# Appending to path in linux

Tags: linux, bash, python

So I've just installed the python anaconda package on a scientific linux system (I have no `sudo` privileges), using the given bash script.

I've checked `.bashrc` and anaconda has correctly added `export PATH="/home/USER/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`. But I can't use iPython and the terminal still uses the system default python.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are the results of `echo $PATH` and `which python`?  Is something later in your bashrc overwriting the PATH change?

Comment: Just to be sure: You replaced the ```USER``` with your username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `.tcshrc` instead.

This is because the terminal wasn't using `bash`, so I had to put the export statement into `.tcshrc` instead of `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you expand this answer to make it more useful to others with the same problem?

Comment: Add this answer as an edit to your question instead.

Comment: If you are setting the path for `tcsh` in `.tcshrc` then you would set the path as:  `setenv PATH $HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @fd0 maybe it is better to try before `setenv PATH $PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin` to minimize the search time for all the other cases.